# Grails: cannot enforce SSL on /**

Tags: grails, ssl, spring-security

I want to enforce SSL for the entire application.

I have the following in Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition = [
        '/**':               'REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL',
]
```

And I start Grails in dev mode with `run-app -https`. The start-up message confirms SSL is enabled (and I also tested it successfully with a browser):

`Browse to http://localhost:8080/foo or https://localhost:8443/foo`

If I browse to `http://localhost:8080/foo`, I am *not* redirected to the `https://localhost:8443/foo` but stay over http. The ports are the default ones (as seen).
This is a local access, as seen, so a load balancer and the extra headers it adds are not applicable. I read the [manual](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/17%20Channel%20Security.html) but cannot see what else is required.

Environment: Grails 2.3, Spring Security Plugin 1.2.7.3

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the [main documentation](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/channelSecurity.html) where I copied it from gives the property as `grails.plugin.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition` instead of `grails.plugins.springsecurity.secureChannel.definition` (plugins, not plugin). However, for version 1.2.7.3 the docs is [here](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual.1273/guide/17%20Channel%20Security.html) where `plugins` appears, probably a rename between versions.